# Psycopg2 Hangs when connecting to RDS AWS via AWS Lambda

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, psycopg2

I have found similar questions with answers, but none of them have been effective.

1. I have configured lambda such that it is in the same VPC as the RDS. The RDS is hosting a PostgresQL Database.
2. I have allowed traffic from the Lambda Security group to the RDS Security group (by changing the inbound permission on RDS SG)
3. The lambda function hangs on the `psycopg2.connect()` call.

Any advice or pointers to resources is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you modified execution role to allow lambda work in a vpc? Also is the lambda and rds in a private subnet? If you launch an ec2 instance in the same subnet, does it connect to rds, or not? Wonder if this is lambda-specific issue or more general rds problem.

Comment: @Marcin I just 10 minutes ago got a successful connection via my lambda function. Since there was no critical data I was able to delete the RDS instance, and create a new one. I then created a new security group for the lambda functions. (I think it may have been some weird interaction by only using the default SG) This was able to solce my issue. Thank you for your reply! First question on SO, and it was cool to get a reply so fast!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out.